# Why can't I change attribute of a class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, immutability, mutable

We say `classes` are mutable in Python which means you can using references we can change the values that will be reflected in object. For example,

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3]
>>> B = A
>>> B[2] = 5
>>> A
[1, 2, 5]
```

Here I can change the values of `A` object using `B` because `list` is a mutable type. My question is why can't I change the attributes of a class below using same concept:

```
class C:

    apple = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.dangerous = 2

D = C # D is pointing to same class C

D().dangerous = 5 # changing the value of class attribute D

D().apple = 3 # changing the value of apple here

print D().apple

print D().dangerous

OUTPUT:
2
2
```

Could anyone explain why the output is `2` and `2` but not `3` and `5` since we are saying that the class is a `mutable` type.

UPDATE : Referring to the answer by @zxq9, if you see the below diagram when do `D=C`, `D` is actually pointing to the same class rather a new object as you have described. Could you explain this:

[image]

Comment: What in the world are people downvoting this for? The OP asked a pretty clear question, just didn't realize the syntactic difference between instantiated objects and class definitions.

Comment: @zxq9 Can you see my updated pic?

Comment: Yes, but *you are still only ever assigning to a temporary instance of the class* not the class itself. I'll toy with this and expand my answer to cover this as well. Its a *very* good thing to keep in mind with Python.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each time you place parens after a class, you are constructing a *new instance object of the class*. So the things you printed were brand-spanking new and did not reflect the short-lived assignments you had made previously.

Here is an example (expanded to cover the underlying reference to class C):

```
>>> class C:
...   red = 2
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.blue = 2
... 
>>> C.red
2
>>> C.blue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'C' has no attribute 'blue'
>>> C().red
2
>>> C().blue
2
>>> #OOOOH!
... 
>>> z = C()
>>> z.red
2
>>> z.blue
2
>>> D = C
>>> D.red
2
>>> D().red
2
>>> D().red = "over 9000!"
>>> D.red
2
>>> D.red = "No, really over 9000!"
>>> D.red
'No, really over 9000!'
>>> C.red
'No, really over 9000!'
>>> #OOOOOOHHHH!
...
```

Note that we *did* change the class directly when I assigned `D.red = "No, really over 9000!"` -- because that was referencing the *class definition itself*, not an instantiated object created from it. Note also that assigning an attribute of D (a copy) changed the attribute of C (the original) because in many (but not all) cases Python makes such assignments *by reference*, meaning that D is really an *alias* of C, not copy of the underlying structure. Read up on Python's [deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) method for more about that particularly startling detail.

Walk through the example code carefully, note the difference between *referencing* `ClassName` and *calling* `ClassName()`. The first is a *reference* via a variable name to a class definition -- a blueprint for generating instance objects that carries a constructor function `__init__()` with it. The second is an *invokation* of `__init__()` whose return value is an instance object of the class within which it is defined.

This is also why you can do things like this:

```
def some_fun(another_fun, value):
    another_fun(value)

def foo(v):
    return v + v

def bar(v):
    return v * v

some_fun(foo, 5)
some_fun(bar, 5)
```

This feature lends Python a high degree of flexibility in building functional abstractions. (Now if only it had tail-call elimination...)

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting example.

1. The line **D().dangerous = 5** will change the attribute "dangerous" of the instance **D()**; But the line **print D().dangerous** print out the attribute "dangerous" of **ANOTHER** instance **D()**.
2. The line **D().apple = 3** will **create** an attribute "apple" in the instance **D()** since this instance does not have the attribute "apple".
3. The line **print D().apple** will print out the attribute "apple" of the class **D** since the instance **D()** does not have the attribute "apple".
4. One way to change the attribute "apple" of the class through its instance is by using **D().__class__.apple=3**